# What is the effect of adding a user on a MySQL slave?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, ubuntu-12.04

This is on a Ubuntu 12.04 server running MySQL 5.5 which is slaved to an OS X server running MySQL 5.1

Logrotate has been sending

```
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysql
/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log '
```

Turns out that there's supposed to be a "debian-sys-maint" MySQL user. I'd imagine that got blown away when the master database was imported.

My question is: Is it all right to re-add the "debian-sys-maint" user to the slave, or do I need to add it to the master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the slave was not set to replicate the mysql database, so the user won't get blown way when the slave updates.

Answer (score 2):

You must add it to the master or it'll get blown away again when the database replicates over.

Comment: Is your `mysql` database replicated?

Comment: It is a slave to the OS X database.